# AWS Integration

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I am integrating AWS with an external application sailpoint iiq. i have given all the details like access keys, role name, page size, and account id. I am facing this error:- InsufficientPermissionException ] [ Possible suggestions ] The Service account must be present in the management account with the required permissions. [ Error details ] Test Connection Failed: You don't have permissions to access this resource. (Service: AWSOrganizations; Status Code: 400; Error Code: AccessDeniedException; Request ID: 7db7ae72-f5c1-43f7-9237-a41cc5038be6; Proxy: null). All permssion are also alloted.

I have removed object type OU from the app. Allotted all important permissions also